# Не сравнивает время изменения с текущим

Tags: cmd, bat

Есть код батника, его задача:
-Проверять время изменения файла с текущим
-Если по истечению 5 минут с момента последнего изменения, время изменения не менялось, то батник должен закрыть программу и запустить ее с параметрами

Проблема в том, что батник перестал проверять время изменения, в результате чего при запуске закрывает программу и запускает ее, не убедившись, что изменялось время изменения файла по истечению 5 минут

```
::время разницы лога с текущим
Set N=5

::путь\имя.файла
::Лучше поместить батник в папку с файлом и указать только имя файла с расширением
set file= test.txt
set /a const=%N%*60

::достаем дату изменения
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ('"%file%"') do set A=%%~tI

echo %a%
set mon=%a:~3,2%
::месяц
set D=%a:~0,2%
::день
set h=%a:~11,2%
::часы
set m=%a:~14,2%
::минуты

::переводим время изменения (часы минуты) в секунды
set /a Hs=H*3600
set /a Ms=M*60
::время изменения в секундах
set /a Ts=Hs+Ms


::достаем текущую дату
@echo off
set now=%DATE: =0% %TIME: =0%
echo %now%
set mon1=%now:~3,2%
::месяц
set D1=%now:~0,2%
::день
set H1=%now:~11,2%
::часы
set M1=%now:~14,2%
::минуты

::переводим текущее время (часы минуты) в секунды
set /a Hs1=H1*3600
set /a Ms1=M1*60

::текущее время в секундах
set /a Ts1=Hs1+Ms1

::если новый месяц для времени изменения 
If %mon1% GTR %mon% (set /a Mons=D*86400) else set Mons=0

::переменная времени изменения для сравнения
set /a TimeI=Ts+mons


::если новый месяц
set /a y=d+d1
If %mon1% GTR %mon% (set /a Mons1=y*86400) else set Mons1=0

::если новый день
If %D1% GTR %D% (set Ds1=86400) else set Ds1=0

::переменная текущего времени для сравнения
set /a TimeT=Ts1+Ds1+Mons1-const-TimeI
set /a mm=TimeT/60
set /a n2=mm+n
set /a n1=timet+n*60
::проверка разницы времени
if %n2% GEQ %N% (TASKKILL /f /im 1cv8.exe
                "C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\8.3.9.2170\bin\1cv8.exe" ENTERPRISE /S "srv4.sm.local\Тест_sev" /N"Рассказов Евгений" /P"1111") 
else pause

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю воспользоваться функцией для подсчета времени в универсальном формате.
В написанном мною примере она вынесена в отдельную функцию 2UTC. Это предложение сделано на предположении, что функция может понадобиться в других батч-файлах.

```
@set file=c:\WINDOWS\WindowsUpdate.log
@REM Get file timestamp
@for /f %%I in ("%file%") do @set tm=%%~tI


@call:2UTC "%tm%
@set timestamp=%utc%

@call:2UTC "%date% %time%
@set nowtime=%utc%


@REM Calc time difference in minutes
@set /a lag=(nowtime-timestamp)/60
@echo %lag%

@goto end


:2UTC    - here starts the function. Parameter format="dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS.......
@REM - output variable name = %utc%. Second's ciphers can be skipped. Ex.:   "dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM

@set ts=%1
@set ts=%ts:~1%
@set /a "yy=10000%ts:~6,4% %% 10000, mm=100%ts:~3,2% %% 100, dd=100%ts:~0,2% %% 100, H=100%ts:~11,2% %% 100, M=100%ts:~14,2% %% 100, S=100%ts:~17,2% %% 100"
@set /a z=(14-mm)/12, y=yy-z, utc=y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400+(153*(mm+12*z-3)+2)/5+dd-719469, utc=utc*86400+H*3600+M*60+S
@goto end


:end
```

Comment: В указанном примере вместо вывода разницы, хранимой в переменной %lag%, можно дальше дописать нужный код    if %lag% geq 5 (taskkill /f /im 1cv8.exe)